# How to load data from Python and save to a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I am working on a project in which I need to use some libraries in Python, however, the majority of the project will be coded in Javascript (React Native).

I am currently playing around calling Python from JavaScript, and I want to save data called from Python to variables in my JavaScript file.

Here is the code I am currently playing around with:

index.js

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const process = spawn("python", ["./hello.py", 4]);

var result;

process.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  result = parseInt(data.toString());
});

var newNum = result * 10;
console.log(newNum);
```

hello.py

```
import sys

sum = 0
sum = int(sys.argv[1])
sum = sum*3

print(sum)
```

However, the console output is just "undefined", what do I do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Since Node.js is asynchronous, you'll need to wait for the child process to exit before trying to operate on the `result`.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since Node.js is asynchronous, you'll need to wait for the child process to exit before trying to operate on the `result`. Let me illustrate:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const process = spawn("python", ["./hello.py", 4]);
// A process was started in the background, and your code continues...
// You declare a `result` variable, whose value is `undefined`...
var result;
// Python might still be starting up at this point...
// You register a handler for output from the process, but it might not get called
// yet since your computer is from 1996 and it takes a while to start Python...
process.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  result = parseInt(data.toString());
});
// You operate on the `result`, which still is undefined...
var newNum = result * 10;
// Oh! Hey! Python started in the background! It printed out some data, and now the data handler from before got called! Yay! `result` is indeed 12 right now!
// but... you know... let's print `undefined * 10`.
console.log(newNum);
```

You could instead wait for the stdout stream to end:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const process = spawn("python", ["./hello.py", 4]);

var result;

process.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  result = parseInt(data.toString());
});

process.stdout.on("end", () => {
  var newNum = result * 10;
  console.log(newNum);
});
```

Or the process to exit:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const process = spawn("python", ["./hello.py", 4]);

var result;

process.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  result = parseInt(data.toString());
});

process.on("exit", () => {
  var newNum = result * 10;
  console.log(newNum);
});
```

And you can wrap this up into a neat helper function that returns a promise (untested, sorry):

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

function spawnAndCaptureOutput(command, args) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const process = spawn(command, args);
    let stdout = "";
    let stderr = "";
    process.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
      stdout += data.toString();
    });
    process.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
      stderr += data.toString();
    });
    process.on("close", (code) => {
      resolve({ stdout, stderr, code });
    });
    // TODO: error handling?
  });
}

spawnAndCaptureOutput("python", ["./hello.py", 4]).then(
  ({ stdout }) => {
    const number = parseInt(stdout);
    console.log(number * 8);
  },
);
```

Comment: Ok, this works in regards to getting the new number, but let's say I want to use that data amongst other parts of my program in that JavaScript file?

Comment: The promise function should help there, since you get the output as a string.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, and I am unsure if you know what I mean.

Let's say I am working with some data in my JS file, and I need Python to carry out some modifications on that data, I want to be able to call a function, that then returns a value that I can assign to a variable to be used in my JS file.

For example, I want the value retrieved from Python to be stored in a GLOBAL variable in my JS file.

Comment: Ok, I think I may have a workaround, I won't know until I try and fully implement what I intend to do with the JS and Python methods. But, I think that during the ```process.stdout.on("end"...``` method, I can call another function and pass that value into it, the issue I am having is assigning that value returned by Python to a new variable. Thanks for the help.